# Reversing an array in C using aux variable

Tags: c

I need to reverse an array only by using aux variable. Not only print it in reverse but actually reverse its content.

Here is my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define dim 4

int main() {
    int v[dim], aux = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        scanf("%d", & v[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dim / 2; i++) {
        aux = v[i];
        v[i] = v[dim - i];
        v[dim - i] = aux;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        printf("%d", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

But after running the code I get `1 4 3 2`, what am I doing wrong?

EXAMPLE:

```
Input: `1 2 3 4` 

Output:  `4 3 2 1`
```

Comment: `v[dim-i]` should be `v[dim-i-1]`. As `i` goes from 0 to 3, `dim-i` goes from 4 to 1 - which is off by one.

Comment: What is the input to your program? What is the expected output? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should go a long way in helping you understand the problem).

Comment: `v[dim - i - 1]`

Comment: @Amadan all I get now is 4 3 3 2

Comment: @DmitryBychenko all I get now is 4 3 3 2

Comment: Did you change it in _both places_?

Comment: @CoderDisorder: 1) enable all warnings, 2) learn how to debug programs (steping through code, adding watches). It's far more efficient than asking random people on the internet to find bugs by looking at your code.

Comment: Solved it using what @DmitryBychenko said. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark it as solved then

Comment: @Amadan: Better do not answer via comment. Better place a real answer instead.

Comment: @GeoAoe: SO marks a question as "solved" if an answer had been given and the OP checked it.

Comment: An easy way and a good practice to debug your programms is to print the values of the variables you suspect. For example I am sure that you could find the problem yourself if you had put this printf inside the loop. printf("i=%d dim-i=%d aux=%d v[dim-i]=%d\n",i, dim-i ,aux,v[dim-i]);

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define dim 4

int main()
{
    int v[dim],aux=0;
    for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<dim/2; i++)
    {
        aux=v[i];
        v[i]=v[dim-i-1];
        v[dim-i-1]=aux;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

run and result:

```
$ gcc b.c && ./a.out
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
```

The problem is: use `v[dim-i-1]` instead of `v[dim-i]`, two places should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a very small logical error @CoderDisorder. You are giving the index of the array wrong.

1. Since array indexes start from `0` and end in `length-1`, while swapping values, you need to give the upper bound index as `dim-i-1` instead of `dim-i`. Just so that it is more understandable, the `for` loop ranges from `0` to `dim/2` which is `2`. Hence if you want the last element's index which is 3, or the 2nd from last element whose index is 2, it should be `dim-i-1  (4-i-1)`.

Just make this change in the two places where you are using these and the output is there!

Code:

```
for (int i=0; i<dim/2; i++)
{
    aux=v[i];
    v[i]=v[dim-i-1]; //observe the change here index is made dim-i-1
    v[dim-i-1]=aux; //same change here
}
```

2. Another possible way. Almost the same, just a slight difference, Just change the second `for` loop into the following leaving the remaining unchanged.  => `i < dim/2 - 1`

   `for(int i = 0; i < dim/2 - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is zero, `dim+i` equals to `dim` and `v[dim-i]` is the same as `v[dim]` which is out of range. consider using `dim - i - 1`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  const size_t dim = 4; // size_t is more suitable
  int v[dim], aux = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < dim / 2; i++) {
    aux = v[i];
    v[i] = v[dim - i - 1];
    v[dim - i - 1] = aux;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    printf("%d", v[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input : `1 2 3 4`
Output : `4321`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to the other answer I am going to post a `aux` variable free version of this that works only for integers.
In order to swap two integers there is not need of any additional auxiliary variable.

```
for (int i=0; i<dim/2; i++)
{
    v[i]           = v[i] ^ v[dim - i - 1];
    v[dim - i - 1] = v[i] ^ v[dim - i - 1];
    v[i]           = v[i] ^ v[dim - i - 1];

}
```

[Live demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6Pe3dt1HVjc0yE1I)